# How to Compare Strings In Two Different VARCHAR Columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am in need of a way to compare the content of two `varchar` columns, named `fistname` and `lastname` correspondingly, and if the content exists in `firstname`, then remove it from `lastname`.  Ideally, I would like to do this w/o an update query, but if that is the only way to achieve it then I can go that route.

Here is sample DDL and DML:

```
Declare @BadData Table
(
    firstname varchar(500)
    ,lastname varchar(500)
)

Insert Into @BadData (firstname, lastname) Values
('Bridget Jones', 'Jones, III'), ('Butch', 'Jones'), ('Key West', 'West')
,('Bob Marly', 'Junior')

Select * From @BadData
```

Which gives the resultset of:

```
firstname       lastname
-------------   ----------
Bridget Jones   Jones, III
Butch           Jones
Key West        West
Bob Marly       Junior
```

My desired resultset is:

```
firstname       lastname
-------------   --------
Bridget Jones   , III
Butch   Jones
Key West    
Bob Marly       Junior
```

I want to remove the *text* (that is, the content) from the `lastname` column if it exists in the `firstname` column.

How can this be done via a UDF or case statement in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: See if the following functions would work for you: [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/]

Comment: I get a 404 error from the link

Comment: @IcyPopTarts, try https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: IcyPopTarts: you have to add  @user120572 to your comment if you want that user120572  will get a message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I've used an split string function that I've borrowed (again) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36368345/3270427). And I've added an ID column (I suppose your table has some PK field to identify every record.)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable
> (
>     Id int IDENTITY,
>     FirstName varchar(500),
>     LastName varchar(500)
> )
>
> INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) 
> VALUES ('Bridget Jones', 'Jones, III'), ('Butch', 'Jones'), ('Key West', 'West'),('Bob Marly', 'Junior');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(@Input Varchar(1000), @Splitter VarChar(10)) 
> RETURNS TABLE AS
> RETURN
>     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Data 
>     FROM (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@Input, @Splitter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A 
>     CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
> GO
> ```

Now, using a CROSS APPLY with your data:

> ```
>     SELECT *
>     FROM   MyTable t1 
>     CROSS APPLY fnSplit(t1.FirstName, ' ') t2
>     WHERE CHARINDEX(t2.Data, t1.LastName) > 0;
> GO
> ```

You can identify the records where `LastName` contains any word of `FirstName`:

> ```
> Id | FirstName     | LastName   | Data 
> -: | :------------ | :--------- | :----
>  1 | Bridget Jones | Jones, III | Jones
>  3 | Key West      | West       | West
> ```

Using ID's returned from previous query you can update your table:

> ```
> WITH found AS
> (
>     SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Data
>     FROM   MyTable t1 
>     CROSS APPLY fnSplit(t1.FirstName, ' ') t2
>     WHERE CHARINDEX(t2.Data, t1.LastName) > 0
> )
> UPDATE     T1
> SET        T1.LastName = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(T1.LastName, Data, '')))
> FROM       MyTable t1
> INNER JOIN found t2
> ON         t1.Id = t2.Id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

And this is the final result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM MyTable;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | FirstName     | LastName
> -: | :------------ | :-------
>  1 | Bridget Jones | , III   
>  2 | Butch         | Jones   
>  3 | Key West      |         
>  4 | Bob Marly     | Junior
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cb87928d4cb9c367161d6ae373aba526)*